# can't find package fileutil in TCL(how to install it for third party TCL interpreter)

Tags: tcl

I have Win 7 machine and TCL installed from 
[downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTCL/releases/8.6.4.1/ActiveTcl8.6.4.1.299124-win32-x86_64-threaded.exe](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTCL/releases/8.6.4.1/ActiveTcl8.6.4.1.299124-win32-x86_64-threaded.exe)
I am using TCL package *fileutil* successfully , as:

```
proc foo{} {
 # some code 
  package require fileutil
  # able to use ::fileutil::updateInPlace in code 
}

foo
```

This is done by script at

> C:/SVN/code/changeFile.tcl

Now, I use same code as part of bigger script as

```
proc foo{} {
     # some code 
      package require fileutil
     # some code using the package

    }

# more code
cd "C:/SVN/code"
foo
#more code
cd "C:/Program Files (x86)/Target Compiler Technologies/adsp2-12R2/designs/adsp2/ISS"
```

This is part of script called *audio_sim.tcl* ,and is invoked by following commands on shell

> cd "C:/Program Files (x86)/Target Compiler
>   Technologies/adsp2-12R2/designs/adsp2/ISS" adsp2_ia.exe -T -t
>   "C:/SVN/code/audio_sim.tcl"

This now gives error:

> can't find package fileutil

Why it complains now when it is similar to what I did in the first case?

Comment: In the first instance the script is being executed by tclsh.exe (or tclsh86.exe)   which comes with your ActiveTcl. In the second instance it is being executed by adsp2_ia.exe which is a 3rd party program that has a built-in tcl interpreter. That's why it can't find the package. Tcl is a bit unique in this sense because unlike say Perl or Ruby you'd often find it as a scripting language in another program. Much like javascript. This is like writing javascript code for Firefox that won't run in IE. I don't have the solution to this so I'm posting this as a comment.

Comment: @slebetman so I guess I need to find way to install this package for third party interpreter

Comment: If the package is pure tcl code then you can just search for the file that implements the package, source it then do package require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As slebetman wrote, `adsp2_ia.exe` probably can't find the ActiveTcl library files, but you can import the package yourself. In my 8.6.1 installation, the file is at `C:\Tcl\lib\teapot\package\tcl\teapot\tcl8\8.2\fileutil-1.14.8.tm`. Your location or version number may be different, but note that you are looking for a `.tm` file. It will not be in any directory named `fileutil`, those are for related packages.

(Another slebetman pointer:) It may be possible to make the module visible by calling `::tcl::tm::path add` with the path as argument.

If not, use `source` to import the code. Make the call in the global scope, outside of any procedure.

Then you should be able to call `package require fileutil`.

Documentation: [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm), [tm](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tm.htm)

Comment: For .tm files it's better to do `tcl::tm::path add` instead of sourcing. That is, if the interpreter supports it. For older interpreters (very likely) you'd need to source it.

Comment: @slebetman: yep. I thought suggesting ´source` would make it easier and more likely to work in a non-standard interpreter, but of course `::tcl::tm::path add` should be mentioned for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterLewerin and slebetman Thanks guys..you were savior. I found the location and did a _source_ after  _::tcl::tm::path add_ and it works great.

Comment: @user915783: only one of path add and source is necessary. Try path add and then package require first. If that doesn't work, use source and package require instead. Doing both won't hurt, but it's unnecessary.